# How to enforce maven to check if xml files contains some content?

Tags: xml, maven, svn, maven-plugin

I use SVN externalproeprties to set the version author and revision, but this is a big project with hundred of files and sometimes developers forget to add the following lies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- $Rev:: 1161                 $:  Revision of last commit.-->
<!-- $Author:: Xelian  $:  Author of last commit.-->
<!-- $Date:: 2016-07-11 13:13:20#$:  Date of last commit.-->
```

Is there a easy way to check if files from given directory contains `<!-- $Rev::`,`<!-- $Author::`,  `<!-- $Date::` and if not Maven build to fail?

I looked for the enforcer plugin but it does not provide such a rules.

Comment: For SVN, I would also (or rather) use a pre-commit hook for this kind of task.

Comment: How can I define such hooks?

Comment: Why do you set version author and revision into files? You can look into the svn history who has done something on a particular file. If you are in a Maven project you have a version of the resulting artifact that's it. Why do you need to set information into files?

Comment: Because these files are manual send to our clients and they check them. They do not have access to our repository. And sometimes they said "This file is wrong" but they use the old version. For that we want to store the version in the files itself.

Comment: pre-commit hooks are scripts that are executed server-side (on the SVN server) before the commit can occur. There should be plenty of available documentation and samples around the web. Compared to a Maven-based validation, the main disadvantage would be that if you use another SCM (like Git), your validation will be lost.

Comment: This is specific logic only for one folder in our project and this is specific for the project. The efford which I will spend in this will be very big to convince the SVN to make a hook for this to open ticket and so on. For that reason I need maven solution or some exec with regex but for Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use checkstyle.

Checkstyle has rule to verify that files contain specific header:
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_header.html

There is a plugin for maven:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/

Comment: The problem is that I have checkstyle in this project and its behavior is not to fail when find a problem. But if I add such a rule I have to make to fail. Which means that on every check styleerror my build will fail.

Comment: You can add second configuration for check style with this rule (maybe other more) and configure to fail if something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer myself:

```
<properties>
    <groovyVersion>2.4.7</groovyVersion>
    <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.5</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
<artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <scripts>
        <script>file:/${pom.basedir}/scripts/Script.groovy</script>
    </scripts>
</configuration>
```

Then I create a script with Groovy:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []
def dirToCheck = new File(project.basedir,"dirToCheck")

dirToCheck.eachFile(FileType.FILES) { currentFile ->
    String fileContent = currentFile.getText("UTF-8");
    if(!fileContent.toLowerCase().startsWith("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"".toLowerCase())){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n File:"+ currentFile.absolutePath+" does not starts with xml declaration");
    }
}
```

Then execute

```
mvn generate-sources
```

And if there is an error the Build will fail.